# ImageView not using alphachannel of bitmap

Tags: android, opengl-es, imageview, alpha

I have a little problem with rendering an object offscreen to create a bitmap of it and displaying it in an imageview. It does not shot the alpha channel correctly.

It works fine, when I save the bitmap as png and loading it then. But when I directly load it into an imageview, I will see a white background, which is the actual background color without the alpha channel.

Here the code for exporting the bitmap from my EGL Surface:

```
public Bitmap exportBitmap() {
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(w*h*4);
    GLES20.glReadPixels(0, 0, w, h, GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer);
    Log.i("Render","Terminating");
    EGL14.eglMakeCurrent(oldDisplay, oldDrawSurface, oldReadSurface, oldCtx);
    EGL14.eglDestroySurface(eglDisplay, eglSurface);
    EGL14.eglDestroyContext(eglDisplay, eglCtx);
    EGL14.eglTerminate(eglDisplay);
    return bitmap;
}
```

And here the code for setting the imageview (r is the class containing the previous function):

```
Bitmap bm;
bm = r.exportBitmap();
ImageView infoView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.part_icon);
infoView.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

Do I have to set some flags on the ImageView or set something in the config of the bitmap?

I'll add some code examples plus images to clarify the problem:
First the way I want it to work:

```
bm = renderer.exportBitmap();
```

[image: No Alpha]

Second the way it works, with the save to png workaround:

```
bm = renderer.exportBitmap();

//PNG To Bitmap
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+getName()+".png";
bm.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, new FileOutputStream(new File(path)));
bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
```

[image: PNG Workaround]

Third to clarify my premultiplied. Alpha is taken into account the wrong way:

```
        bm = renderer.exportBitmap();
        for(int x=bm.getWidth()-50; x<bm.getWidth(); x++) {
            for(int y=bm.getHeight()-50; y<bm.getHeight(); y++) {
                int px = bm.getPixel(x,y);
                bm.setPixel(x, y, 
                        Color.argb(255,
                        Color.red(px),
                        Color.green(px),
                        Color.blue(px)));
            }
        }
```

[image: Image with black rectangle]

Sorry for the long post.

Comment: Did you have a look in the raw bytes that you get after `glReadPixels`? Can you see the correct alpha values there? Furthermore, did you enable the alpha channel for your EGL context? Are you sure that the byte order is correct, when you receive *RGBA* data from `glReadPixels` but create a bitmap with *ARGB* byte order?

Comment: I did enable the alpha channel in the egl config. The coloring of the object is correct (blue, red, green actually tested). Additionally if I save the Bitmap as png through bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, new FileOutputStream(new File(path))); it has the correct coloring and alpha channel.

Comment: I just checked. The values that are white, which should be translucent are 0. so (0,0,0,0). This should mean that the values are premultiplied. When I set the alphachannel to 255, the image is black. So it seems to be a android display issue, since it does not render the actual black values and instead shows white values.

Comment: I think I still did not completely understand the problem. When your values are (0,0,0,0) then they are completely translucent, which means the background "beneath" the image should be drawn. If this background is white by default (I don't know), white will be rendered. When you set the alpha channel to 255, which means you get (0,0,0,255) RGBA values, then it *should* be black.

Comment: That is exactly the problem. The value is (0,0,0,0). The color beneath is some greyvalue and white gets drawn by the image. So android recognizes the alpha channel, but does not show the background underneath the imageview. Again. If I save and load it as png the image is translucent.

Comment: This indeed sounds strange. Did you try out using [BitmapFactory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html) with [BitmapFactory.Options property "inPremultiplied"](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inPremultiplied)?

Comment: The values are premultiplied (0,255,255,255) becomes (0,0,0,0). And bm.isPremultiplied() returns true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the exportBitmap() function. Basically I read the pixels and write them again. This is solving the problem. I really don't know why. It would be nice, if somebody could explain it to me. It is not that clean to create a new integer array for these bitmapdata.

```
public Bitmap exportBitmap() {
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(w*h*4);
    GLES20.glReadPixels(0, 0, w, h, GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer);

    //This is the modification
    int[] pixels = new int[w*h];
    bitmap.getPixels(pixels, 0, w,0, 0,w, h);
    bitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, w,0, 0,w, h);

    EGL14.eglMakeCurrent(oldDisplay, oldDrawSurface, oldReadSurface, oldCtx);
    EGL14.eglDestroySurface(eglDisplay, eglSurface);
    EGL14.eglDestroyContext(eglDisplay, eglCtx);
    EGL14.eglTerminate(eglDisplay);
    return bitmap;
}
```